# How can I return a class from a TypeScript function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

I'm using TypeScript with a dependency injection library which works very similar to Angular 1 - basically: *register a factory with your dependencies as arguments*.

This is how I would register a class in ES6

```
export let factory = () => {
    return class Foo {}
};
```

If I write the same in TypeScript:

```
export let factory = () => {
    return class Foo {}
};
```

It fails to compile with the error

> error TS4025: Exported variable 'factory' has or is using private name 'Foo'.

Is there any way to allow TypeScript to return a class from a factory function?

Answer (score 23):

#### Quick answer

change this:

```
export let factory = () => {
    return class Foo {}
};
```

to that:

```
export let factory = () : any => {
    return class Foo {}
};
```

---

#### Longer answer

This error could be triggered/forced by  to a *tsconfig.json* setting:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "declaration": true // this should be false or omitted
```

But that is not the reason, it is just a trigger. The real reason (as discussed here [Error when exporting function that returns class: Exported variable has or is using private name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034979/1679310)) comes from the Typescript compiler

when TS compiler founds statement like this

```
let factory = () => { ...
```

it must start to guess what is the return type, because that information is missing *(check the **`: <returnType>`** placeholder)*:

```
let factory = () : <returnType> => { ...
```

in our case, TS will quickly find out, that the returned `type` is easy to guess:

```
return class Foo {} // this is returned value, 
                    // that could be treated as a return type of the factory method
```

so, in case we would have that similar statement *(this is **not the same, as original statement** at all, but let's just try to use it as an example to clarify what happens)* we can properly declare return type:

```
export class Foo {} // Foo is exported
export let factory = () : Foo => { // it could be return type of export function
    return Foo
};
```

that approach would be working, because the **`Foo`** *class* is exported, i.e. visible to external world.

Back to our case. **We want** to **return type** which is **not exported**. And then, we MUST help TS compiler to decide, what is the return type.

It could be explicit any:

```
export let factory = () : any => {
    return class Foo {}
};
```

But even better would be to have some public interface

```
export interface IFoo {}
```

And then use such interface as *return type*:

```
export let factory = () : IFoo => {
    return class Foo implements IFoo {}
};
```

Comment: good answer! And now it works even with declaration: true! :) However, your final suggestion is exactly what I did try in the beginning - that does not work: Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.

Comment: @MiB I would say, that this is another issue. Check this playground [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20IFoo%20%7Bx%3Aboolean%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20let%20ISfactory%20%3D%20()%20%3A%20IFoo%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20Foo%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B) ... showing such issue.. in case, if `IFoo` as interface requires something.. which `Foo` does not implement... in that example `IFoo {x:boolean}` requires **x** but class does not have it `class Foo implements IFoo {}` hope it helps a bit

Comment: I guess that's true, but in my case adding `public x: boolean = false;` to `class Foo` still results in the same error. Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20let%20ISfactory%20%3D%20()%20%3A%20IFoo%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20Foo%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Using the `any` type only hides the problem, it does not solve it. This is not a real solution.

Answer (score 8):

Late answer on old question:

You need to have the class defined outside the factory method and define return value using 'typeof'.

```
class Foo {}

export const factory = (): typeof Foo => {
    return Foo;
};
```

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? Thank you @Niels Steenbeek

Comment: Sometimes `factory` takes arguments which are used to define the class, in which case this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a proper way to do it:

```
export let factory = () => {
     class Foo {/* ... */}
     return Foo as (new () => { [key in keyof Foo]: Foo[key] })
};
```

[Check it out on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAG2PAZgQwMY2gTzgXjgAoBKAgPjgG8BYAKDkbgwTQGc24AxCCa+poLhoCcAMwBuAUMYAjUQHJZaKAukyMAfgBccWbyRoAdurgBfU1GQBXKEe69hnIkeAB3YmXyUqcANoA1sB4AJb2QTgQKA4QALq6PBCBwbHmJPRmUnT0GBBGbPCJAMJ5BVCi6Fi4pPQ5paiOhK4exfVQNXRAA)

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the class as well so that the consumer of the method can access the type.

Typically a factory will return an instance rather than a class or constructor.

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

```
export class Foo {}; 

export let factory = () => {
    return Foo;
};
```

With ES6 you don't need to export the class type, but with TypeScript you absolutely should exporting the type signatures.

Comment: Not terribly helpful given the use case of returning a dynamically generated class (e.g. React HOC).

Comment: The original question is about implementing the Factory pattern in typescript (using AngularJS), and resolving a compiler error. It says nothing about generating a dynamically generated class.

Comment: @Martin the question literally contains only an example of a dynamic class.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt yes that is because ES6 is a dynamic language, where the question is how to do it in TypeScript -- which adds type signatures.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [separately provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656830/3182819) satisfying:

```
export class MyClass {
   ...
}

export type MyClassRef = new (...args: any) => MyClass;
```

Given that signature I can use `MyClassRef` as a type of return value:

```
exposeMyClass(): MyClassRef {
    return MyClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same error. The solution for me was to remove the

```
"declaration": true
```

from `tsconfig.json` or to set it to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

## How to create a function that return a class.

---

**Including static functions!!!**

I have used generics to make sure every implementation of the factory has a different outcome but nothing is stopping you from just have an if/else statement inside your factory function

```
type Animal = {
    kind: string,
    age: number,
}

type AnimalFactory<T extends Animal> = {
    new(): {
        sayAge: () => number;
    },
    validate: (obj: Record<string, unknown>) => obj is T;
}

function AnimalFactory<T extends Animal>(Base: T): AnimalFactory<T> {
    return class Animal {

        sayAge(): number {
            return Base.age;
        }

        static validate(obj: Record<string, unknown>): obj is T {
            return 'kind' in obj
        }
    }
}

const Dog = AnimalFactory({ kind: 'dog', age: 20 })
const dog = new Dog();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Are you looking for returning Type of class from the function? Below is one code snippet how we can implement factory in TypeScript similar to in other languages.

```
    class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
class Factory{
    getObject(msg:string): Greeter {
        return new Greeter(msg);
    }
}
var greeter = new Factory().getObject("Hi");
console.log(greeter.greet());
```