# Is there a type for "Class" in Typescript? And does "any" include it?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Java, you can give a [class to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873003/2725515) as a parameter using the type "Class". I didn't find anything similar in the typescript docs - is it possible to hand a class to a method? And if so, does the type "any" include such class-types?

Background: I'm having an issue with Webstorm, telling me that I cannot hand over a class to `@ViewChild(...)` in Angular 2. However, the Typescript compiler does not complain. The signature of `@ViewChild()` seems to be `"Type<any> | Function | string"`, so I wonder if any includes Classes or not.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The equivalent for what you're asking in typescript is the type `{ new(): Class }`, for example:

```
class A {}

function create(ctor: { new(): A }): A {
    return new ctor();
}

let a = create(A); // a is instanceof A
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create(ctor%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20A%7D)%3A%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20new%20ctor()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20create(A)%3B%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20instanceof%20A))

The code above will allow only classes whose constructor has no argument. If you want any class, use `new (...args: any[]) => Class`

Comment: Note that `{ new(): Class }` can also be written as `new () => Class`. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.1/doc/spec.md#3.8.9

Comment: And note that you probably want `new (...args: any[]) => Class`. The proposed code in this answer will allow only classes whose constructor has no argument, which is probably not what you're after.

Comment: New angular global type link https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/interface/type.ts

Comment: My class also has static methods, will they be included in the type this way?

Comment: @ArturKlesun you'll have to add them to the type, i.e.: `{ new(): A; fn1(num: number): number; }`

Comment: Thanks. Or use `typeof Class` as I found out after scrolling down a bit =3

Comment: This doesn't work for classes with private constructors that only expose static factory methods (such as [LocalDate](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/LocalDate.html))

Comment: @Gili - as far as I recall, `private` members are not accessible outside of the declaring class, and private constructor signatures are not an exception - I am not sure a truly generic solution can be provided for `class` factory pattern implementations. Shouldn't something like this - `const createPrivate = (ctor: { init(): A }) => ctor.init();` (granted, it allows any object with `init` method returning an instance of `A`, but it is an inherent issue of structural type system used in TS).

Answer (score 90):

The simplest solution would be `let variable: typeof Class`.

Here an example:

```
class A {
  public static attribute = "ABC";
}

function f(Param: typeof A) {
  Param.attribute;
  new Param();
}


f(A);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using the function call syntax fails when you want to access static properties, otherwise

Comment: This approach breaks down once you start having inheritance among classes and your classes have different constructor signatures. (Think `class B extends A` with a constructor that takes more arguments than `A`'s constructor.) In such case, the compiler won't accept `f(B)`.

Comment: @Louis True, this was rather thought as a quick way to have a constructable with static members. Inheriting class types must be constructed via `{new<T>: (a: T) => Instance<T>, staticMember: string}`

Comment: Perfect. This enables typehint for static members.

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger why cant i use `let variable: Class`, instead of `let variable: typeof Class`. Basically why cant i use class as the type directly without `typeof`

Comment: because `let variable: Class` means that `variable` must be *an instance of* `Class`. You have to use `typeof` if you want it to be the class itself.

Answer (score 35):

Angular internally [declare](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.6/packages/core/src/type.ts#L25) `Type` as:

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }
```

With TypeScript3 it should be possible to add [types for arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html) without function overloading:

```
export interface TypeWithArgs<T, A extends any[]> extends Function { new(...args: A): T; }
```

Example:

```
class A {}

function create(ctor: Type<A>): A {
    return new ctor();
}

let a = create(A);
```

Answer (score 25):

> is it possible to hand a class to a method? And if so, does the type "any" include such class-types?

Yes and yes. `any` includes every type.

Here's an example of a type that includes only classes:

```
type Class = { new(...args: any[]): any; };
```

Then using it:

```
function myFunction(myClassParam: Class) {
}

class MyClass {}

myFunction(MyClass); // ok
myFunction({}); // error
```

You shouldn't have an error passing in a class for `Function` though because that should work fine:

```
var func: Function = MyClass; // ok
```

Answer (score 9):

**`Type<T>`** from `@angular/core` is a proper interface for Class.

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

You can use it to keep reference to class, instead of instance of this class:

```
private classRef: Type<MyCustomClass>;
```

or

```
private classRef: Type<any>;
```

---

According to background of your question with `@ViewChild`:

**@ViewChild** allows to inject `"string selector"` / `Component` / `Directive`

Signature of `Type<any> | Function | string`
is an abstract signature that allows us to inject all of above.

Comment: sadly it fails when you try `classRef : Type<Foo> = (new Foo()).constructor`

Comment: @l00k constructor is a function, and unfortunately typescript doesn't know that you can create new instance using `new` operator on function in JS.  Typescript expects class

Comment: That only means constructor property is wrongly typed. Cuz at runtime class and its constructor are the same `A === A.prototype.constructor` and `(new A()).constructor === A`

Answer (score 8):

Following worked for me:

```
type ClassRef = new (...args: any[]) => any;
```

my use case:

```
 interface InteractionType { [key: string]: ClassRef; }
```

Comment: sadly it fails when you try `classRef : ClassRef<Foo> = (new Foo()).constructor`

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a type that includes only classes:

```
declare type Class<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution without using `typeof` :

Typescript has a utility type called `InstanceType`, its declaration is :

```
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

You can use it to declare your own class type with following code :

```
interface ClassType<InstanceType extends {} = {}> extends Function {
  new(...args: any[]): InstanceType
  prototype: InstanceType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those going nuts out there, try one of these types:

```
export type Constructor<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
export type Class<T = any> = InstanceType<Constructor<T>>;
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368495