# How to implement a factory method in typescript?

Tags: typescript

My code:

```
class Model {}

class Loader {
    static load<M extends Model>(ModelClass: typeof Model): M {
        return new ModelClass();
    }
}
```

Error message: `Type 'Model' is not assignable to type 'M'.`

Link to Playground: goo.gl/qrSsoX

Answer (score 1):

We should say that `load` take a class as argument not an instance.

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }

class Model {}

class Loader {
    static load<M extends Model>(ModelClass: Type<M>): M {
        return new ModelClass();
    }
}
```

for more information take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183279/5801495) answer

Comment: And how can this problem be solved? Plz see: goo.gl/DqEeBs

Comment: Is that right?
`static load<M extends Model>(ModelClass: Type<M> & typeof Model): M {...`

Comment: I guess so, TypeScript have  [problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600) with `static` methods.

Comment: Since `Type<T>` is an interface for the static side of the class (i.e., the constructor function), not the instance, you can declare `m1` directly as a method of `Type<T>` without the `static` modifier.

Comment: Sure, if you are happy with intersecting with `typeof Model`, that is a fine solution.