# Difference in TypeScript between types `InstanceType<typeof MyClass>` and `: MyClass`

Tags: typescript, constructor, instance, typescript-typings

I've been trying to understand if there is any difference between using `InstanceType` to assign a type, or simply using the Class name.

In particular, given the class:

```
MyClass {

  public static foo: string = 'abc'

  public makeFoo() {
    // awesome maker
  }

}
```

When I want to use an instance of the class, it seems that there is no difference between:

```
// inside some other Class
private myClassInstance: InstanceType<typeof MyClass> 
...
this.myClassInstance = new MyClass()
```

and

```
// inside some other Class
private myClassInstance: MyClass 
...
this.myClassInstance = new MyClass()
```

At least in VSCode I don't get any visible difference in using any of the two. However I guess a difference must exist, if TS has implemented `InstanceType<>`.

Anyone knows if there is a difference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `InstanceType` helper type exists because there are actually two things:

- Classes are actually functions in JavaScript (more precisely constructor functions, but mainly functions)
- The return of these constructor functions is of one certain type (the `prototype` of the constructor function and optionally some instance fields)

In TypeScript, when you declare a `class`, you actually declare both things: the type of the constructor function and the type of the generated instances (class fields and methods).

In your example, when you write `class MyClass` you actually create one JavaScript class and two TypeScript types:

- `MyClass`: a kind of interface which contains the class fields and methods
- `typeof MyClass` (in this case `MyClass` refers to the runtime class): the constructor function

As you didn't specify a constructor function, its type is `new () => MyClass` and you can extract `MyClass` out of it thanks to `InstanceType`.

As a real-world example, imagine you are trying to implement a factory (function that returns instances of classes). One naive implementation would look like this:

```
declare function factory<T>(ctor: T): T;

class A { }

const res = factory(A); // typeof A: not what we expect
```

This doesn't work because we actually return the type of the constructor function itself.

However, this implementation works:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any;

declare function factory<T extends Constructor>(ctor: T): InstanceType<T>;

class A { }

const res = factory(A); // A: what we expect
```

Because `InstanceType` helped us declare that the return value type is the **constructor's return value** type.