# Type of Class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to type a method, where I pass a class and a factory as an argument. Both should strongly point to type T, but the compiler is okay with the following simplified test. Is there a stronger approach to type a class reference?

```
type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T
class A { }
class B { }
const test = <T>(type: Class<T>, factory: () => T) => { }
test(A, () => new B()) // why is this accepted?
```

I tried all answers from [Is there a type for "Class" in Typescript? And does "any" include it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392853/is-there-a-type-for-class-in-typescript-and-does-any-include-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), commonly called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Notice that if I make the classes themselves structurally different, you get the expected behavior:

```
class A { foo = "" }
class B { bar = 0 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUB8UC8UB2EA7lABQB0lCATgOZIBcUC+IA2gLoCUu26AsACgAxohRQAglADeUAGYB7BbigAiVVAC+Q0ciRQAQjKgAjGioAMWnQvxJgUYBHsqMmUqEhN4etwBp5BGFgBWoQJlIeHD4o7FltQSd7UgkAyN4CYkNIngB6XKgiAAsQKABLfWAiiuZhYQgwJwATAH4hIA)

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't this imply that one difference is enough?
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUB8UC8UB2EA7lABQB0lCATgOZIBcUC+IA2gLoCUu26AsACgAxohRQAglADeUKAF8ho5EigAhGVABGNXFAAMCpQHt8SYFGARzejJlKhITeCrsAaKADMEw4MeogTKQ8OHwh2LKKglbmpBIewbwExOrBPAD06VBEABYgUACWqsA5RczCwhBgVgAmAPxCQA)

Comment: @AndMic No, because you are expecting A, and B is assignable to A. This is true because A does not have anything, while B has one property. If you don't expect anything to come with something, do you really care?

Comment: Here's the TypeScript docs about type compatibility: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: I do care while developing a strongly typed api under laboratory conditions in the beginning (empty mook classes, interfaces, etc.). This is very confusing and I admittedly  fail to see the advantages of this typing behaviour just yet, but I appreciate your explanations. Thanks!