# Error when exporting function that returns class: Exported variable has or is using private name

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting the error

> error TS4025: Exported variable 'UserApiClientModule' has or is using private name 'UserApiClient'.

in the following code:

```
export var UserApiClientModule = {
  fromConfiguration: (configuration: Configuration) => {
    @NgModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: BASE_PATH,
          useValue: basePath
        },
        {
          provide: Configuration,
          useValue: configuration
        },
        RegistrationApi,
        AuthApi,
        AccountApi,
        ContactsApi,
        ContactOrgsApi
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule
      ]
    })
    class UserApiClient { }

    return UserApiClient;
  }
}
```

I suspect the solution is to export the type UserApiClient somehow but I'm not sure how to do this since it's declared in a function.

Comment: Might be to complicated for AOT. There are other ways to get configuration into Angular2. You can just provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is:

> Typescript tries to guess what is the **returned type** of all the public parts. And not only guess, but to really declare the **`UserApiClient`** as a part of returned type of the **`fromConfiguration`** call

And because we return something, which is not exported, is internal.. there is a problem. But we can easily return something else, e.g. some common interface ... or at least magical **`any`**

```
// change this
export var UserApiClientModule = {
  fromConfiguration: (configuration: Configuration) => {
    @NgModule({
    ...


// to that
export var UserApiClientModule = {                // below is the change
  fromConfiguration: (configuration: Configuration) : any => {
    @NgModule({
    ...
```

I would prefer to declare some common interface `IHaveDynamicData` ... as in fact in similar case shown here [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310)