# How can I use a Class returned by a function as a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on a small library that contains a utility function that generates a Class. This is because the Class has quite a complex signature with a lot of generics. It looks somewhat like this:

```
function generateClass() {
  class GeneratedClass {
    ...
  }
  return GeneratedClass;
}
```

The compiler correctly infers the return type of this function. The only problem is, I cannot use the returned value as a type. This only works if I extend the returned GeneratedClass. For a more elaborate example, see this [TS Playground snippet](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20generateClass()%20%7B%0A%20%20class%20GeneratedClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20bar%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20GeneratedClass%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20FooClass%20%3D%20generateClass()%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20I%20can%20construct%20instances%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20FooClass(5)%3B%0A%2F%2F%20These%20instances%20are%20properly%20typed%0Aconsole.log(foo.bar)%3B%20%2F%2F%20logs%205%0A%0A%2F%2F%20However%2C%20I%20cannot%20use%20the%20class%20as%20a%20type%20%0Afunction%20processFoo(foo%3A%20FooClass)%20%7B%20%20%2F%2F%20cannot%20find%20name%20%22FooClass%22%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Though%20I%20can%20extend%20the%20class%0Aclass%20FooChildClass%20extends%20FooClass%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(foobar%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(foobar%20%2B%201)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20and%20then%20use%20it%20as%20a%20type%0Afunction%20processFooChild(foo%3A%20FooChildClass)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20console.log(foo.bar)%3B%0A%7D).

Is there any way to make the returned class usable as a type? I would rather not require consumers of my library to type `class Something extends generateClass() { ... }`, because that kind of defeats the purpose of the utility function making it more convenient to create these kinds classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return a class from a TypeScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314114/how-can-i-return-a-class-from-a-typescript-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the instance type in several ways:

If you have an instance of the class you can use `typeof` with that variable to type the parameter:

```
  const FooClass = generateClass();

  const foo = new FooClass(5);
  function processFoo(fooParam: typeof foo) { 

  }
```

In typescript 2.8 you can use the conditional type `InstanceType`:

```
const FooClass = generateClass();

const foo = new FooClass(5);
function processFoo(fooParam: InstanceType<typeof FooClass>) { 

}
processFoo(foo);
```

Pre 2.8 you can get the instance type without instatiating using a helper function and a dummy variable:

```
const foo = (function<T>(arg: new (...args: any[])=> T) : T{ return null as any})(FooClass);
function processFoo(fooParam: typeof foo) { 

}
processFoo(foo);
```

In either case you can store the instance type in a `type` alias to use in several places:

```
type GeneratedClass = typeof foo;
type GeneratedClass = InstanceType<typeof FooClass>; // for 2.8
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is an ok solution for me in some situations, but ideally the type is 'returned' from the function somehow instead of the user of the library having to do something to extract the type. This is particularly a pain when you have some complex generics:

Comment: @flut1 2.8 with `InstanceType` is the simplest way.