# how forcing a type instance instead of typeof in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, type-conversion

how can I export a `type` by forcing it to be an instance.

I have tried many ways, I only found one solution, creating a static getter but I would like to remove my static getter.

Here context:
I would like to export a type of a instance of A from there `$A.A`, for ref only.

```js
export const $A = (() => {
    class A {
        static get default() {
            return A.create();
        }
        static create() {
            return new A();
        }
        constructor() {}
    }

    return { A };
})();
```

i try many way, here 7 of them ! no one work instead the way 1 ! but it because i add a static getter in the js class.

```js
export type _1 = typeof $A.A.default;
export type _2 = typeof new $A.A;
export type _3 = typeof $A.A.create();
export type _4 = typeof  $A.A();
export type _5 = typeof $A['A'];
export type _6 =  $A.A;
export type _7 = typeof new ()=>$A.A;

// example somewhere in the project, i want tell A should be a instance and not a typeof!
function foo(A:_6)
```

So what the syntax to emulate a instance in a ts type for export somewhere for typage usage only.
**My project is in js, but using ts only for help the tsserver to understand my refs when he dont.**

- So it for Intelisence in my ide only and no for generate ts=>js.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is generic here? I see no type parameters anywhere.

Comment: sry, miss translate , i remove `generic` word

Comment: See e.g. [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307), or [this qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314114/how-can-i-return-a-class-from-a-typescript-function). The related error message you should get is "Exported variable '$A' has or is using private name 'A'.(4025)".

Comment: this is out of context for this question, but it fine the guy above found the tool.
thanks also for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary note: the `class A` code here lacks any instance structure (no properties or methods).  All non-nullish values will be assignable to that instance type; see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) for more info.  Just to avoid this weirdness, I've added a property to the example class:

```
const $A = (() => {
    class A {
        static get default() {
            return A.create();
        }
        static create() {
            return new A();
        }
        constructor() { }
        someStructure = 123; // add structure here
    }

    return { A };
})();
```

Now the compiler can tell that `{someRandomThing: 123}` is not compatible with the `A` type you're having trouble naming.

---

You might want to use [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to pull out the return type of a construct signature:

```
type A = InstanceType<typeof $A.A>
```

You could write this yourself using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type AlsoA = typeof $A.A extends new (...args: any) => infer I ? I : never;
```

Or, you could use the method we had to use before conditional types existed: TypeScript pretends that the `prototype` property of a class is the same as its instance type.  This isn't really true since the prototype generally only contains the methods and not other properties.  But you can use it anyway:

```
type AlsoAlsoA = typeof $A.A.prototype;
```

Any of those should produce the same type.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
function foo(a: A) { }

foo($A.A.create()) // okay
foo({ someRandomThing: 123 }) // error 
// Argument of type '{ someRandomThing: number; }' is 
// not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkUvAPbBQAuSAJAIJIC8SAFCwJRMB8ehx-8DCChQkDAv0nEqISgEt4SAOYRqAEwgAzEAFcMlDrynHiAJ1U7TwMQDp452RA4BuPiaIBfN+5nzF9iEdDCXcpc0pLa2AIAHcxF28TL1CiMgpKUx14SlJTYKRklKhSSABlDKyI8yYkAEYAJgBmZyQAelakEDU1JCpM7MtkAAsIc0TiL3GicMi8MQLXfg92BO9KAE8YZAZmAEl0kGBEABVNiAAeDa3STVo6GzouNbOxDGKdpCuIG7uHpAgAB6UCDANSiaJxFg2aEgUxKKAALk6wHWnEYPDkwE0oyQuyQAH5cUgkdEAG6jRbEL6vd5vUgfL4-egPGwwUykHJfVzeTQ6I7ychITSkUgsEBIuicAjeSb8YWi5n3AJBdicdpIUgAaxA6x5IpYuF6JQgACVDmoSschpilEiGo0CmqOqN2aYkN51XQ4TpIMBqD9qQByQ3FSBm0GW63AW1IYA+gBGFIKgaQcnBHM6IjkSlA8YwyBySDgpnAqhxAZegbogZs+C8QA)

Comment: Thanks you so much, 
`export type Entity = InstanceType<typeof $Entity.Entity > ;`  work like a charm ! i search so long without success in the doc.
" lacks any instance structure" , sure , i remove all for focus on the issu!